# HTML display - div id ....getElementbyId

Tags: html

I am really new to HTML and am stuck conceptualising some code as follows.
  My question is - which part of the code is actually doing the displaying of 'showHello'.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayCD()
{
document.getElementById("showHello").innerHTML="hello";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayCD()">

<div id='showHello'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Doesn't     `document.getElementById("showHello").innerHTML="hello";`
just set id `showHello` to the value `hello` and 
    `<div id='showHello'></div>` just create the id `showHello`?

If `<div id...>` actually displays the value of `showHello`, how does it, if `displayCD()` is called before it or is the whole document deciphered before anything is actually displayed ?

Does that make sense as a question?!!!!

Comment: I didn't understand anything here except the code snippet

Comment: not surprised - I am very confused!

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't document.getElementById("showHello").innerHTML="hello"; just set id showHello to the value hello

It searches the DOM for the element with that id, and changes the HTML inside it to `hello`.

> and  just create the id showHello?

It creates an element with that id

> how does it, if displayCD() is called before it or is the whole document deciphered before anything is actually displayed ?

See this:

```
<body onload="displayCD()">
```

The function is called in response to the load event firing. That won't happen until the entire document, including any dependent resources (such as images) has loaded.

Comment: thank you for answering so quickly.  I explained it really badly but I think what I don't understand is which line actually results in the showHello element being displayed.  If I added a heading before the <div id..> line the heading would be displayed before "hello".  If I added one after the <div id..> line then it would display after..so is <div id ...> the line creating the element and displaying it?

Comment: `<div id='showHello'></div>` as I explained in my answer, step by step

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of what a browser would do is like this:

- create the *document* object
- add the `head` element and interpret the script. This will make him *remember* that there exists a function called `displayCD`.
- add the `body` element.
- add the `div` `HTMLElement` to it and set the `id` property to *showHello*

Note: the `div` is declared here in Hypertext markup language `<div id='showHello'></div>`

- when the *document* has done loading all the elements into it, the function you set on `onLoad` is called. In your case, `onload="displayCD()"` is the part that does that and the function called is `displayCD`.
- `displayCD` will get the `HTMLElement` that has the `id` == *showHello* and set its `innerHTML` property to the *hello* string. Since this is called when the *document* has fully loaded, it means that the div with `id` == *showHello* already exists, so it will add the text *hello* into it.

Answer (score 0):

The line who is in charge for displaying the "hello" is this one

```
function displayCD()
{
    document.getElementById("showHello").innerHTML="hello"; // THIS one
}
```

And the `displayCD()` function is loaded with HTML here

```
<body onload="displayCD()">
```

PS : If you're new with HTML, you probably new with Javascript. Maybe you should look after jQuery. Here is how we doing the same thing with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showHello").html("hello");
});
```

Preview : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypBvf